# Git pull --rebase messes up local branch commit history

Tags: git

I've used the git `pull.rebase = true` for over two years in a cooperative environment without having seen this error before, but now I switched jobs, laptop and everything (not sure which version of git/git-for-windows I was using before) and now this happens consistently on every feature branch I update. Current git version is `2.43.0.windows.1`

We have **develop** as a main branch and I'm starting work at **feature/a**. I'm ready with my changes, I open a PR (no conflicts with **develop**). some time passes and someone else merges in **develop**. There are no conflicts with **feature/a**, but still I wanna update it - `git pull origin develop` (which uses rebase strategy because I have it configured globally) and suddenly my local commit history is a mess - the pulled commits show up somewhere in the middle of mine, even though they are earlier by Date. As a side-effect my local **feature/a** is of course out of sync with remote **feature/a** and pulling causes even bigger mess (in some cases this even leads to duplication of some of my commits).

The original pull from **develop** warns:

> hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
> hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.skippedCherryPicks false"

I have not cherry picked any commits **feature/a** and I have also not merged anything into **feature/a** that might have been merged in **develop**.

How does this make sense?

Comment: What does "someone merges in *develop*" mean? Is *develop* merged into some other branch and your *feature/a* is left alone, or does someone else merge your *feature/a* into *develop*?

Comment: `pull --rebase` _recreates_ your commits on top of upstream. This rewrites history and you are required to force-push ("out of sync"). `pull --rebase` rewrites history in the same way as regular `rebase` does. Pulling (with `--merge`) will merge the remote, original commits into your local, rewritten commits. Everything works as designed, I'd say. Which behavior exactly is confusing?

Comment: A git log graph would be appreciated.

Comment: @j6t it means **feature/b**, which is completely independent from my **feature/a** was merged into **develop**.

Comment: My Gut feeling is that the right solution is not to rebase, but to merge feature/a as well.

Comment: How are you viewing your log when you witness this, "the pulled commits show up somewhere in the middle of mine". I suspect you're just doing a command line `git log` instead of `git log --graph`.

Comment: > pull --rebase rewrites history in the same way as regular rebase does.
Not exactly, since `git pull --rebase` defaults to fork-point mode, but I do not think this comes into play in the situation described.

Comment: @j6t why? I don't understand why rebase would be problematic in this situation and I don't understand how I had no such problem before.

Comment: @TTT  I haven't tried graph. Unfortunately this situation is already resolved and I didn't keep a copy branch, I'll post again when it happens again.